Do central simple algebras have unique complex faithful irreducible representations?
I'm looking through some online notes by Trautman on spinors and it is implied there, as far as I can tell, that central simple algebras have unique faithful complex irreducible representations.
Is this correct and where can I find a proof?

Note that over $\mathbb{C}$ a central simple algebra is just an algebra isomorphic to $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Over any simple (or more generally local) Artinian ring, there is a unique irreducible module. Any nonzero module over a simple ring is faithful. These are standard facts that will be treated in basically any text on noncommutative algebra.
I'm a bit confused about the mentioning of complex representations of a central simple algebra. Can you clarify what you mean? Are assuming that the central simple algebras are defined over $\Bbb C$ or over $\Bbb R$?
Let me assume that the center $K$ of your central simple algebra $A$ is a subfield of $\Bbb C$. In this case, one might define a complex representation of $A$ as a complex vector space $V$ equipped with an action of $A$ making $V$ into an $A$ module such that the two actions of $A$ and $\Bbb C$ are compatible on the sense that they agree on $K$ and for any fixed $a\in A$, the map $V \to V, v \mapsto av$ is $\Bbb C$-linear.
With this definition, complex representations of $A$ are equivalent to left $A \otimes_K \Bbb C$-modules. But a base change of a central simple algebra along an arbitrary field extension is again a central simple algebra, thus $A\otimes_K \Bbb C$ is a central simple algebra over $\Bbb C$ and hence a simple Artinian ring, thus the first paragraph applies.
We have not used anything special about $\Bbb C$ here. If $A$ is a central simple algebra over any field $K$ and $L$ is any field extension of $K$, then there is always a unique irreducible $L$-linear representation of $A$, which happens to be faithful.

Thanks for this. I'm not sure how to resolve your confusion. Trautman works over $\mathbb{k} = \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ and then writes "if the dimension of $V$ over $\mathbb{k}$ is even ... then the algebra $Cl(V, g)$ is central simple; as such it has only one, upto equivalence, irreducible and faithful complex representation". This suggests that even over a real ground field he is considering complex reps.

What would count as a standatd text on noncommutative algebra?

As I mentioned, as long as the base field is contained in $\Bbb C$, the definition I gave is basically the only sensible one, so there is no issue.

Standard texts are Lam - A First Course in Noncommutative Rings ir Benson/Farb - Noncommutative Algebra
